# Cox Regression approach

Tags: regression, self-study

I wonder if you could help me understanding how to answer this exercise question:

[image]

This is what I've managed to think of so far:

[image]

Does it make sense? In question 3 in particular i didn't know what to say about significance.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you've tried so far and we'll help guide you.

Comment: Do you think this model used time-varying predictors? Are there other reasons for preferring Cox PH regression?

Comment: Is it wrong to consider age as a time-varying predictor? The reason for using Cox PH regression in this case I think is that it is the most common tool for studying the dependency of survival time on predictor variables. That's what I can think of at least.